# Как отследить загрузку другой страницы вместо текущей в этой же вкладке браузера?

Tags: javascript

Имеются несколько проектов на одном домене, которые реализованы не в виде поддоменов, а как отдельные папки в одном.

Мне необходимо отслеживать какие из них сейчас открыты в браузере и когда конкретный из них закрывается, то на сервере надо выполнить какие-то действия. Для закрытия вкладки с этим отлично справляется такой вариант:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    // тут аяксом отправляю данные на сервер
};
```

Но вот если открыта одна вкладка, в ней загружен один из проектов и я в той же вкладке перехожу к другому (по ссылке или набрав его адрес явно), событие onbeforeunload не срабатывает. Могу ли я как-то отследить, что ранее открытый в этой же вкладке проект уже закрыт?

Comment: Предполагаю, что можно попробовать посмотреть на вебсокеты

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь то JavaScript работает только в открытой вкладке

Comment: @MonkeyMutant ошибаешься

Comment: @АлексейШиманский с каких пор js стал работать в других вкладках?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant  с каких пор "ту же вкладку" называют "открытой"? И да, есть слушатели для работы с данными на другой вкладке. Например банально событие storage для localStorage позволяет вполне себе что-то отследить в изменениях хранилища другой вкладки того же домена. Есть ещё postMessage например и слушатель на message...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский точно, я не профи если помнишь, спасибо за консультацию..